# Problem with FPDM in FPDF : FilterFlateDecode: invalid stream data

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

i have a problem with FPDF. When I want to use FPDM to merge a pdf with data from database, I face that Error

```
FilterFlateDecode: invalid stream data.
```

thats happen when i use a pdf that i create or edit with a pdf software .And thats how i want to use it : 
[FPDM example.](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php)

Thank you

Comment: Welcome! To ask [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we don't write code for you.**

Comment: Than kyou
first i tried a lot of solutions

Comment: Than kyou
first i tried a lot of solutions
and i have search for solutions in internet and i found nothing
and What I discovered is that the problem is in PDf , maybe it need a special pdf

Comment: First, FPDM has nothing to do with FPDF. Second, FPDM is not compatible with all PDFs.

Comment: Then what kind of PDF is comatible with ?

Comment: and i was thinking thst FPDF a library in FPDF ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will , Thank you guys .
i found a solution .

the solution is very easy :
you need to create PDF using Adobe Acrobat
but before Saving you work you need to uncheck Fast web view and Save as optimizes for Fast web view
you'll find them in :
Edit -> prefernces then search of Internet and uncheck "Fast web view"
and search of Documents and uncheck "Save as optimizes for Fast web view"
Now save it , Then go to cmd and ut this command : pdftk modele.pdf output modele2.pdf

modele.pdf is your PDF file , modele2.pdf is the file with Modification just name it with any name you want.
But you need to have been already installed PDFTK tool

and now the file is ready to use .